# Different links for a product is beneficial or harmful for seo?

Tags: url, seo, hyperlink, opencart

Opencart produces different links for a product like:

```
website.com/product_name
website.com/category/product_name
website.com/category/subcategory/product_name
website.com/brand/product_name
etc.
```

It is based on the listing page which you reach to product. My question is that, using different links for a product/content is beneficial or harmful for seo? 
I will make it one link if it is harmful or unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I find it bad for SEO. From what Google says, it really doesn't matter too much since it just ignores duplicate content not penalise as some suggest - plus each product page has the canonical URL's which again Google will make use of. However, if you are looking for something to make your URL's more consistent, I have [an extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5023) (commercial) which does make them all uniform across the site (and also makes the pages breadcrumbs the same too)

Comment: As long as the URL in every page has a canonical link. It is OK. Ideally you want them on your product direct link and not through brand or categories. Jay Gilford answer is correct.

Comment: Another importance of the canonical is that it groups all your social events. e.g Facebook likes. and avoids them getting diluted over all those different URLs.

Comment: Didn't know that, interesting