# OpenCart: How to make product URLs with full category path

Tags: php, url, opencart

Products on my shop now have URLs like this:

> example.com/category1/product1

or

> example.com/category1/subcategory1/product1

and it's one and the same product only assigned into 2 categories. URL depends on if you go from *cateogry1* or *subcategory1*.

I want to force opencart to always go to `example.com/category1/subcategory1/product1` (the deepest subcategory).

Do you know how to do it? I didn't find any extension for it. I'm gonna probably have to change `/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php` but I'm not sure what to change and I don't wanna brake it.

I'm running on OpenCart 1.5.6.

Comment: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5023

Comment: @JayGilford Thanks, but is there also any free solution? I think all i need is some little change in seo_url.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different links for a product is beneficial or harmful for seo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697968/different-links-for-a-product-is-beneficial-or-harmful-for-seo)

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin panel and open category form and remove the seo keywords for the category and the subcategory.

Then you will get full path of the category.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some code to do this without extension.

In controller/seo_url.php add this function

```
public function getFullProductPath($product_id) {

    $path = array();
    $categories = $this->db->query("SELECT c.category_id, c.parent_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c ON (p2c.category_id = c.category_id) WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'")->rows;

    foreach($categories as $key => $category)
    {
        $path[$key] = '';
        if (!$category) continue;
        $path[$key] = $category['category_id'];

        while ($category['parent_id']){
            $path[$key] = $category['parent_id'] . '_' . $path[$key];
            $category = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id, parent_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category WHERE category_id = '" . $category['parent_id']. "'")->row;
        }

        $path[$key] = $path[$key];
    }

    if (!count($path)) return '';

    // wich one is the largest ?
    $whichone = array_map('strlen', $path);
    asort($whichone);
    $whichone = array_keys($whichone);

    $whichone = array_pop($whichone);

    return $path[$whichone];
}
```